# Finding given date is in the wanted range using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a task to enter data and generate reports form them using php and mysql. The data is retrieved from database within given range of start date and end date. There in the generated report I want to give users to edit data by using "contenteditable"if the entry time of the record satisfy one of below .

1.If the record entry time is in this week

2.If the current time is before Tuesday midnight the user can edit the last week record which having entry time of last week

The format of entry time of the record is  like this

2015-07-31 18:44:30

then

```html
if (record entry time satisafy abovw 2 points){
data with that record entry time can edit
}
else{
canit edit
}
```

how can I find the time range to do above. Please help me.
for now I am doing this

```html
 //getting today's date
            $timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));//getting today's date

            $day = date('w', $timestamp);
         //   print_r($day);
            //according to today's date defining content editable records
            if($day==0){
                $start_edit_date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday'));
                $end_edit_date= date("Y-m-d") ;
            }
            if($day==1){
                $start_edit_date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday'));
                $end_edit_date= date("Y-m-d")  ;
            }
            if($day==2){
                $start_edit_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-8 days'));
                $end_edit_date=date("Y-m-d") ;
            }
            if($day==3){
                $start_edit_date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday'));
                $end_edit_date=date("Y-m-d") ;
            }
            if($day==4){
                $start_edit_date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday'));
                $end_edit_date=date("Y-m-d") ;
            }
            if($day==5){
                $start_edit_date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday'));
                $end_edit_date=date("Y-m-d")  ;
            }
            if($day==6){
                $start_edit_date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday'));
                $end_edit_date=date("Y-m-d")  ;
            }
            $start_edit_date=$start_edit_date." 00:00:00";
            $end_edit_date=$end_edit_date." ".date("H:i:sa");
            echo"You can edit your record between ". $start_edit_date." and ".$end_edit_date;
```

It works fine but is there any better way for getting the range.

Comment: please try something and let stackoverflow know the issue you are facing. :) question is valid so I am not down voting.

Comment: show your actual code. we can't fix pseudo-code, and we're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding actual code

Comment: So data has a timestamp? Whats the query you use to fetch the data from DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely shorten up that script with a function:

```
<?php
function GetDates($timestamp = false)
    {
        $today      =   date("Y-m-d");
        $timestamp  =   ($timestamp != false)? $timestamp : strtotime($today);
        $day        =   date('w',$timestamp);

        $use[0] = $use[1] = $use[3] = $use[4] = $use[5] = $use[6] =  date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday'));    
        $use[2] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-8 days'));

        $use_dates['start'] =   $use[$day]." 00:00:00";
        $use_dates['end']   =   $today." ".date("H:i:sa");

        return $use_dates;
    }

// Assign dates
$dates  =   GetDates(); ?>

<p>You can edit your record between <?php echo $dates['start']; ?> and <?php echo $dates['end']; ?>.</p>
```